# Qual é a finalidade no uso de chaves "{ }" para acessar a propriedade de uma classe?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Estava fazendo alguns testes com o método magico `__get` do PHP e descobri uma forma diferente de acessar as propriedades da classe, que é usando chaves `{ }`, veja:

```
return $this->{$bar};
```

Eu também posso acessar a propriedade da forma tradicional, que seria:

```
return $this->bar;
```

E o resultado obtido me pareceu o mesmo. Agora veja um exemplo de ilustração completo:

```
class Foo 
{
    private $bar;
    private $prop = ":(";

    public function __construct($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function __get($bar)
    {
        if ($this->{$bar}) return $this->{$bar};
    }

    public function getProp()
    {
        return $this->{$prop};
    }
}

$obj = new Foo("SOpt");

echo $obj->__get('bar');
```

Saída:

> SOpt

Perceba que, se eu utilizar esta sintaxe em um método **get** tradicional `getProp()`:

```
return $this->{$prop};
```

eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> <br />
> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: prop in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
> <br />
> <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot access empty property in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
> ```

O exemplo de ilustração pode ser executado [aqui](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9ac416a474172c9b95825da2031492638f971d94).

Isso me deixou com algumas dúvidas que eu abordarei abaixo.

## Dúvidas

1. Qual é a finalidade em usar as chaves `{ }` para acessar a
   propriedade de uma classe?
2. Esta forma de acessar as propriedades só funciona com métodos
   mágicos ou pode servir para outros contextos?

Comment: Da uma lida aqui: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php Resumindo é usado mais quando quer criar um nome que vem de várias outras variáveis ou pra especificar algo mais complexo.